# Excel annoyingly turns entered date to computed formula

Tags: excel, date, format

When I enter a date in excel, it computes it as a formula. Example, "6/15/2020", turns to "=6/15/2020" and the result is "01/01/1904"

Anyone know how I can stop this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Advanced section of Excel Options, at the bottom, uncheck the 'Transition formula entry' option in the Lotus compatibility settings part.